# Add custom borders to Alert Dialog Builder Layout

Tags: java, android, material-design, androidx, material-components-android

I'm trying to add a custom layout with borders to my Alert Dialog builder, but this is the result I got:

[image]

I created a style for my dialog:

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
</style>
```

And this is how I defined it:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid
    android:color="#00000000" />
<stroke
    android:width="5dp"
    android:background="#00ffffff" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
```

Then, in the layout I defined this as well:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
android:gravity="center"
style="@style/MyDialog">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/myCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:text="Abilitare la palette di colori?" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Inserisci l'eta'">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myCheckBox"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/maleRadioButton">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Maschio" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/maleRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Femmina" />
</RadioGroup>
```

1) Why the **OK** button is out of the shape?
2) How can I make the background transparent since I cannot use the `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);` method?
This is the Java code of the Alert:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setView(formElementsView)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
                            int selectedId = genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) formElementsView.findViewById(selectedId);
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaintingActivity.class);
                            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            if (myCheckBox.isChecked()) myIntent.putExtra("palette", "yes");
                            else myIntent.putExtra("palette", "no");
                            myIntent.putExtra("gender", selectedRadioButton.getText());
                            String eta = nameEditText.getText().toString();
                            if (eta.length()!=0) myIntent.putExtra("eta", eta);
                            else myIntent.putExtra("eta", "0");
                            myIntent.putExtra("protocollo", "a");
                            myIntent.putExtra("cornice", "1" + "");
                            myIntent.putExtra("userLogged", userLogged);
                            myIntent.putExtra("first", "yes");
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }

                    }).show().getWindow().setLayout(600, 600);
```

Comment: If you want an ok button don't define it as `.setPositiveButton` rather define it inside the xml.

Comment: if you want to fit border to layout then remove corner <corners android:radius="20dp" />  in shape

Comment: if you want to border to whole layout then you can define custom dialog using DialogFragment and apply the same. Since you are defining the button in using setPositivebutton attribute .i guess it wont be applicable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new [Material Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) you can [customize the shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#customizing-component-shapes) of your component using the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute.

Something like:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MyThemeOverlayAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

You can also define the style for all dialogs in you app adding this attribute in your theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"> 
    ...
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/MyThemeOverlayAlertDialog</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: This, for me at least, sets the "cancel" and "ok" buttons as rounded and not the dialog itself..

Answer (score 0):

**Why the OK button is out of the shape?** -

> Beacause you have used `.setPositiveButton("OK",..` If you want an OK
>   button define it directly on the customized xml file.

**How can I make the background transparent** -

> Set a background to the customized layout just like you have created
>   the shape and adding a color to it. Place it in the root layout.

A relatable example,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<!--Transparent background for outermost layout-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/alert_background_xml"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

<!--alert_background_xml is your customized style -->
    <!--Your views and buttons here including the OK Button-->

    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Fabio remove the `.setPositiveButton`